# How to make images fit a TD without wrapping on different screen resolutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following  element:

```
 <td>
                        <h4 style="margin-top:16px;">Your images</h4>

                        <div  id="container">
                        <img src="http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/413816437/photo-413816437.jpg">
                            <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/238987906/photo-238987906.jpg">
                            <img src="http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/233499883/photo-233499883.jpg">
                            <img src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/232630345/photo-232630345.jpg">
                            <img src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/232630354/photo-232630354.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </td>


#container{
  border: 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: nowrap
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto
}
```

The td contains between 4 and 8 images.

However, depending on screen resolution or number of images the images can wrap and display in two rows on the screen.

What I want to achieve via CSS (if possible?) is to have the images always on one row, not wrapping. For this I would need the images to autoadjust in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try css rules :

```
<html>
<title>Demo</title>
<head>
    <style>
        td {
            width: auto;
            background-color: red;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }

        td img {
            width: 150px;
            background-color: green;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 4px;

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h4 style="margin-top:16px;">Your images</h4>

            <div id="container">
                <img src="http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/413816437/photo-413816437.jpg">
                <img src="http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/238987906/photo-238987906.jpg">
                <img src="http://thumb101.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/233499883/photo-233499883.jpg">
                <img src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/232630345/photo-232630345.jpg">
                <img src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/thumb_large/1207028/232630354/photo-232630354.jpg">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this code

```
<style>

        td {
            width: 100vw;
        }

        img {
            min-width: 24%;
        }

    </style>
```

change the min-width % depending upon the images you want on 1 row.